# Fast Segmentation

Tags: image-processing, mesh, image, segmentation

Imagine I have an image of a segmented tissue as follows

[image]

what is the fastest way of converting such an image into a mesh-type object in *Mathematica*? I am familiar with `Watershed` and `ColorConvert`, but any attempts seem too slow, for an already decently segmented image. Any ideas/suggestions?

For example, `ImageMesh[ColorNegate@img]` gives me

[image]

which is not quite what I want, since there are spaces in between cells, but perhaps it could be easily obtained from this? Is there a way of, for example, joining the spaced mesh regions (given a spacing threshold)?

Comment: What do we see in this image?

Comment: @Szabolcs Segmented epithelial cells. I want a mesh approximating this tissue. `ImageMesh` almost gets me what I want, but returns 'gaps' in between cells.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the planar graph functionality of [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

Load the package:

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]
```

Import the image:

```
im = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEeHv.png"]
```

We delete small disconnected components and convert to a graph:

```
gr = MorphologicalGraph@DeleteSmallComponents[im]
```

Note that this replaces edges with straight lines. If you need to preserve the curvature of edges, a more advanced replacement for `MorphologicalGraph[]` would be needed.  Having worked with similar images, I'd say that currently the easiest way is to use other tools than Mathematica for this step.

We delete tree-like components, i.e. start with degree-one vertices are prune back the graph. This gets rid of parts belonging of faces that are only partially in the image.

```
gr = IndexGraph@VertexDelete[gr, IGTreelikeComponents[gr]]
```

The purpose of `IndexGraph` to ensure that the `i`th vertex is named `i`. We will rely on this when constructing the `MeshRegion` later.

Compute faces based on the actual embedding, and drop the largest face, which will be the outer face.

```
faces = Most@SortBy[IGFaces@IGCoordinatesToEmbedding[gr], Length];
```

Construct the mesh:

```
MeshRegion[GraphEmbedding[gr], Polygon[faces]]
```

[image]

Comment: When loading the package, I get the messages "Get::noopen: Cannot open IGraphM." and "Needs::nocont: Context IGraphM was not created when Needs was evaluated.". Any idea why?

Comment: @samwolfe Because you did not install the package. This is a package I wrote. It does not come with Mathematica as standard. Follow the link for installation instructions.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

- Another approach which similar with @Szabolcs
- We use `PlanarFaceList` to get the  list of faces of the planar graph.
- We use `PositionIndex` to rearrange the indexs of the points in `GraphEmbedding`.

```
Clear[img,g,faces];
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEeHv.png"];
g = WatershedComponents[img] // Image // ColorNegate // 
   MorphologicalGraph;
faces = PlanarFaceList[g];
MeshRegion[GraphEmbedding[g], 
 Polygon[faces[[2 ;; Length@faces]] /. 
   First /@ PositionIndex[VertexList[g]]]]
```

[image]

```
MeshRegion[GraphEmbedding[g], 
 Polygon[faces[[1]] /.First /@ PositionIndex[VertexList[g]]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Outline :**

- **Discussion**
- **Method 1 : Vectorized/Graphics thinning**
- **Method 2 : Thinning and `FindCurvePath` from points**

#### Discussion

Not sure if the lines of the image are enough for your purpose. If they are then maybe you can use the code below.

The **methods below are very slow when working on the entire image**. I did not check if it works for the entire image. I will apply the method to the following crop of the image:

[image]

The advantage of the code below is that it does not rely on branching points and so it shows the shape of the cells rather than flattening them to connect to branching points.

**Edit :** added the method below that implements a form of vectorized/graphics thinning.

#### Vectorized/Graphics thinning

I made a code to do **thinning on a graphics object**

The method makes a mesh of the image then uses `PolygonDecomposition` then thins each polygon.

Obtaining the polygons:

```
polys = img // Thinning // ImageMesh // CanonicalizePolygon // 
   PolygonDecomposition;
```

The polygon thinning code :

Note: `…=\[Ellipsis]`

```
skeleton…poly[divisions_][poly_] :=
 Module[{ybound, x, y, inequalities, ylist},
  
  ybound = Last@RegionBounds[poly];
  ylist = Subdivide[Sequence @@ ybound, divisions];
  inequalities = 
   poly // Refine[RegionMember[#, {x, y}], (x | y) ∈ Reals] &;
  Table[inequalities /. y -> ypoint // Rationalize[#, 0] & // Reduce //
      Switch[#, _Equal, {#[[2]], 
        ypoint}, _Inequality, {N@Mean[Through@{First, Last}@#], 
        ypoint}, _, Null] &, {ypoint, ylist}] // DeleteCases[Null]
  ]
```

Example:

```
{polys[[1]], Blue, 
  Line@skeleton…poly[80][polys[[1]]]} // Graphics
```

[image]

thin every polygon in the decomposition:

```
polys // Map[Line@*skeleton…poly[80]] // 
  Prepend[Blue] // Graphics
```

[image]

---

#### Thinning and `FindCurvePath` from points

Vectorize the image to prevent errors from pixels in the last plot :

```
img•graphics = img // ImageGraphics
```

[image]

Find the points in the white part after thinning the white part of the image.

```
pts = img•graphics // Image // Thinning // 
   PixelValuePositions[#, White] &;
```

Find an ordering of the points that makes a smooth curve:

```
curve = FindCurvePath[pts];
```

Draw the lines:

```
pts[[#]] & /@ curve // Line // Graphics
```

[image]

**Notice that some of the lines do not connect**

Using [`ListCurvePathPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCurvePathPlot.html)

```
ListCurvePathPlot[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 5]
```

[image]